# logic to show images dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html layout would be such that one image would be small and other would be big. If all images would have been of same size then it could have been easy to loop and create html.

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbfztuqt/).

All images are in article section but first article uses one css class and second one something different.

```
<article class="idea col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="mygal/images/1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="ide">
      <a href="#">
        <p>
          <strong>TTTTTTTTTT</strong>
          <span class="name">/DDDDD</span>
        </p>
      </a>
                                </div>
  </div><!-- /.image -->
</article>
```

Here is expected output.

[image]

How could i produce expected output using javascript. I have code which gets me data but i need logic on how to bind data to produce expected output.

Comment: why downvote? Someone please put comments for downvoting.  I was not expecting ready made code.. just need logic

Comment: I haven't down-voted but you've provided no explanation as to *why* that's your expected layout. What is it that you want?

Comment: @davidthomas i m expected that output because thats what html i got from designer.

Answer (score 0):

In the given example grid, it looks like all images have the same width. I would wrap the images in a div element and give those a fixed width and height. You could set the width of the images to 100% to align with the wrapped divs.

Comment: If you see my fiddle. I have article section.in those section there is image. One article section is bigger than second and then third is same as first. Hope its clear now.now i dont understand how to loop on those section and load images as to get expected output shown in figure